# Integrate Firebase Realtime Database with Google app engine web app (Python API)

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, firebase

Beginner here:
I just learned web development in google app engine using Python API. What I intend to do is use firebase's real-time database with my already built web app. When I go to Firebase doc, I only see support for javascript apps. Can someone please show me the big picture what's going on. Does firebase only integrate with javascript web apps or what?

I understand you inject your javascript code in your Html file. But the app still runs on Python on the server side. How do I incorporate firebase with this??

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is primarily designed to be a realtime database which integrates directly into your browser using JavaScript + WebSockets. It has a feature called Firebase functions which allows you to run server side JavaScript such as NodeJS, and an Admin API which allows read/write of data from other applications.

If you are designed a web application you need to decide which parts of the functionality require realtime technologies, and which use server-side. Normally Firebase would be a good use-case for features such as:

- Notifications
- Chat
- Live updates
- Instant Messaging
- etc

Once you have chosen the features you need Firebase for, you can integrate Firebase into the Frontend using the Web API (JavaScript):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Then you can read/write data in python using the Admin API (Python, Java, NodeJS)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: Please excuse me for the noob talk. I've got this handler .py files which I deployed on app engine. What I don't understand is that can I integrate firebase database into this or not?

Comment: You can read/write the Firebase database using the Admin API (Python). The examples are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start